# C# same parameter type error and ambiguous between methods and property

Tags: c#, parameters

I am having trouble running my code. The error says "The 'Point' already defines a member called 'Point' with same parameter types." for the line 15, "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:'Point.Point(double,double,string)' and 'Point.Point(double,double,string)'.".
please help solve this issue

```
using System;

public struct Point
{
    public double x, y;
    public string name;

    public Point(double x1 = 11.4, double y1 = 34.6, string n1 = "point1")
    {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
        name = n1;
    }

    public Point(double x2 = 1.4, double y2 = 34.6, string n2 = "point2")
    {
        x = x2;
        y = y2;
        name = n2;
    }

    public double horizontal_distance(Point p)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x - p.x, 2) + Math.Pow(y - p.y, 2));
    }
}

public class RunStructs
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point(2.4, 3.6, "point2");

        Console.WriteLine("horizontal_distance: " + p1.horizontal_distance(p2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the method signature is the same for the compiler that is `Point(double, double,string)` no matter what default value you have given to the params.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same signature the compiler is giving you an Error.
However, I have gone through your code and did not understand the need for second-class constructor. Anyway you can look at my below code. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
public struct Point
{
    public double x, y;
    public Point(double x1 = 11.4, double y1 = 34.6)
    {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
    }
    public double horizontal_distance(Point p)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x - p.x, 2) + Math.Pow(y - p.y, 2));
    }
}

public class RunStructs
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point(2.4, 3.6);

        Console.WriteLine("horizontal_distance: " + p1.horizontal_distance(p2));
    }
}
```